# How to select an default window or popup in selenium webdriver?

Tags: automated-testing, webdriver, selenium2

I want to select the current window,frame or popup where my browser is pointing.
(i.e when i doubleclick or click it opens an popup or window) I want to get through that window or popup using selenium webdriver.So if possible please suggest me how to do it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To switch to new pop up window what you can do is the following:

```
String currentWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
String lastWindow = null;
 Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles();
    for (String aux : handles) {
        lastWindow = aux;
    }
    driver.switchTo().window(lastWindow);
```

This will switch you to the new window opened. If you need to switch to the other window just switch to currentWindow.

Hope this helps.

Comment: sure i will work on this.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following code also to handle popup.

```
 String mainwindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
        for (String popup : driver.getWindowHandles()){
            driver.switchTo().window(popup);
        }
// Your code on poppup window
        driver.switchTo().window(mainwindow); //Switching to main/parent window
```

Hope this will help :)

Comment: sure i will try it QA4it

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you can try this,

```
Set <String>handles = driver.getWindowHandles();//To handle multiple windows
firstWinHandle = driver.getWindowHandle(); //To get your main window
handles.remove(firstWinHandle);
String winHandle=handles.iterator().next();  //To find popup window
if (winHandle!=firstWinHandle){
secondWinHandle=winHandle;

driver.switchTo().window(secondWinHandle); //To switch to popup window
```

Make sure to add some delay after switching to next popup,
    Thread.sleep(5000);